# Is there any way to kill my app, other than android.os.Process.killProcess and Sytem.exit(0)?

Tags: android, kill-process

I have a problem with my app. I really need to kill it when user clicks "Exit". I've tried both methods listed in the question header, and here's the problem: I have a persistent (foreground) service performing work, so there is a tray icon for my app. When user switches to my app via this icon and then presses "Exit" - the app is kill, but Android immediately restarts it. If the users switches back to the app using any other method (not the service icon) - application is not restarted upon exit.

So, what is the reliable way of killing application?

P. S. There's always only one activity in the application, if that is of any importance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Quitting an application - is that frowned upon?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found the solution to my problem. If I move my activity to background with `moveTaskToBack(true);` and then kill the process it is not restarted.

Answer (score 0):

for only one `Activity`, I choose `finish()`.

Comment: It' not what I need. I really need to kill the whole process for good.

Comment: So you need to have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon/2034238#2034238

Answer (score 0):

You can use following intent to exit from your activity

```
Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
          startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
          startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
          startActivity(startMain);
```

and Call finish() before you call this intent.

Comment: This does not kill the process.